# how to transform a source object into another object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to `transform` an object or in other words I am trying change text of an object.

I have `two object` one is source and another is `mapped object`.using `mapped object` I want o transform the source object.

example

`source object`

```
{
  "links": {
    "Offering": {
      "id":"offering-id",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "links": [
        {
          "text": "School",
          "id":"school-id",
          "onclickUrl": "https://www.school.com/school/"
        },
        {
          "text": "happy",
          "onclickUrl": "https://www.happy.com/help/",
          "id":"happy-id"
        }    
      ]
    },
    "luck": {
        "iconUrl": "",
       "id":"hospital-id",
        "links": [
          {
            "text": "Student",
            "id":"student-id",
            "onclickUrl": "https://www.student.com/school/"
          }   
        ]
      }
  }
}
```

`mapped -object`

```
let mappingObj = {
  "hospital-id":"hospital-change",
  "school-id":"school-change-xx",
  "offering-id":"Offering-changes-map",
  "happy-id":"happy-cs",
  "student-id":"nnnnnn"
}
```

`expectedout output`

```
let expectedOutput = {
  "links": {
    "Offering-changes-map": {
      "id":"offering-id",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "links": [
        {
          "text": "school-change-xx",
          "id":"school-id",
          "onclickUrl": "https://www.school.com/school/"
        },
        {
          "text": "happy-cs",
          "onclickUrl": "https://www.happy.com/help/",
          "id":"happy-id"
        }    
      ]
    },
    "hospital-change": {
        "iconUrl": "",
       "id":"hospital-id",
        "links": [
          {
            "text": "nnnnnn",
            "id":"student-id",
            "onclickUrl": "https://www.student.com/school/"
          }   
        ]
      }
  }
}
```

I have `id's` in `source obj` same `id's` are present in `mapped obj`.using this I want to change the text of all `properties and keys`.

I tried like that here is my whole code

https://jsbin.com/zaxoyineme/edit?js,console,output

```
let result = {};

function recursiveFn(Obj){
  for(let i in Obj){
   result[mappingObj[Obj[i].id] || i]=Obj[i];
  
  if(typeof Obj[i]==="object"){
    console.log('--obj--');
      recursiveFn(Obj[i]);
  }else if(Object.prototype.toString.call(Obj[i]) === '[object Array]'){
     console.log('--Array--');
    for(var k =0 ;k<Obj[i].length;k++){
      Obj[i].text = result[mappingObj[Obj[i].id] || Obj[i].text]
    }
  }
}
}

for(let i in Obj){
   result[mappingObj[Obj[i].id] || i]=Obj[i];
  
  if(typeof Obj[i]==="object"){
    console.log('----');
    recursiveFn(Obj[i])
  }else if(Object.prototype.toString.call(Obj[i]) === '[object Array]'){
    console.log('--Array--');
    for(var k =0 ;k<Obj[i].length;k++){
      Obj[i].text = result[mappingObj[Obj[i].id] || Obj[i].text]
    }
  }
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

I am using recession to get the expected output.but I am not able to get the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Your code is way to complicated for what you are trying to do. From What I understood this should probably do your job.

```
let Obj = {
  "links": {
    "Offering": {
      "id":"offering-id",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "links": [
        {
          "text": "School",
          "id":"school-id",
          "onclickUrl": "https://www.school.com/school/"
        },
        {
          "text": "happy",
          "onclickUrl": "https://www.happy.com/help/",
          "id":"happy-id"
        }    
      ]
    },
    "luck": {
        "iconUrl": "",
       "id":"hospital-id",
        "links": [
          {
            "text": "Student",
            "id":"student-id",
            "onclickUrl": "https://www.student.com/school/"
          }   
        ]
      }
  }
}


let mappingObj = {
  "hospital-id":"hospital-change",
  "school-id":"school-change-xx",
  "offering-id":"Offering-changes-map",
  "happy-id":"happy-cs",
  "student-id":"nnnnnn"
}


// expected output

let expectedOutput = {
  "links": {
    "Offering-changes-map": {
      "id":"offering-id",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "links": [
        {
          "text": "school-change-xx",
          "id":"school-id",
          "onclickUrl": "https://www.school.com/school/"
        },
        {
          "text": "happy-cs",
          "onclickUrl": "https://www.happy.com/help/",
          "id":"happy-id"
        }    
      ]
    },
    "hospital-change": {
        "iconUrl": "",
       "id":"hospital-id",
        "links": [
          {
            "text": "nnnnnn",
            "id":"student-id",
            "onclickUrl": "https://www.student.com/school/"
          }   
        ]
      }
  }
}

let result = {};
let midResult = {};

function updateObject (Obj) {
  let i = 0;
  let parseArray = Object.keys(Obj.links);
  for (i =0; i < parseArray.length; i++) {
    let id = parseArray[i]
    let matchingId = mappingObj[Obj.links[id].id]
    midResult[matchingId] = Object.assign({}, Obj.links[id])
  }
}

updateObject(Obj);
result.links = Object.assign({}, midResult)



console.log(result)
```